# Dynamically add elements to an array

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, windows-forms-designer, dynamic-arrays

how to get values to an array from textboxes dynamically?
and print those values in a label called "ArrLbl", with interval of 3 seconds.

i used Threading.thread,sleep !but it works only ,when i put MessageBox after each and every threading.thread.sleep

windows form application in Visual Studio 2012

i'm a beginner

help me please

Comment: You wouldn't use a loop at all.  You would use a `Timer` to create the interval between each action.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use Thread.Sleep in your program because Thread.Sleep will stop your program from running during the sleep.  It won't respond to clicks and moves etc.  What you want is a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) which will let your program run normally and will raise an event on a 3 second interval.

You would do something like this:

```
public class MyFrom : Form {
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public MyForm() {
        timer.Interval = 3000; // The interval is in ms
        timer.Tick += new TimerTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Get the value from your text boxes here.
    }
}
```